# error found : artifact.type (with underlying type SA) error required: _$2

Tags: scala

I have simplified this Play Framework controller to the minimum so it shows the problem, and I've mocked Play so this program is complete in itself. The code is question is at the top, and the mocks follow; you can ignore them - they are just so this sample compiles. I made a [git repo](https://github.com/mslinn/lazycontroller/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/micronautics/blah/LazyController.scala) for this code example for your convenience.

```
package com.micronautics.blah

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object LazyController extends Controller {
  case class SecureActionInfo[SA <: SecuredArtifact](allowedRoles: Seq[Role], block: SA => RequestHeader => Html)

  val allCourseTranscripts = (course: Course) => { implicit request: RequestHeader =>
    Html(printTitlePage(course) + course.allTranscripts(showTitlePage = false))
  }

  val secureFetchActions = Map[String, SecureActionInfo[_]](
    "AllCourseTranscripts" -> SecureActionInfo(Nil, allCourseTranscripts)
  )

  def fetchByArtifact[SA <: SecuredArtifact](tabName: String, artifact: SA)(implicit request: RequestHeader) =
    Future {
      val actionInfo: SecureActionInfo[_] = secureFetchActions(tabName)
      val result: Html = if (actionInfo.allowedRoles.nonEmpty) {
        (for {
          user <- Model.maybeCurrentUser
        } yield actionInfo.block(artifact)(request)).getOrElse(Html("Not authorized"))
      } else actionInfo.block(artifact)(request)
      Ok(result)
    }
}

trait SecuredArtifact

class Lecture extends SecuredArtifact

class Course extends SecuredArtifact {
  def allTranscripts(showTitlePage: Boolean) = "Title page"
}


// Mocks follow

case class Role(name: String)

trait Controller

trait RequestHeader

case class Html(text: String)

case class User(name: String)

case class Ok(name: Html)

case object Model {
  def maybeCurrentUser = Some(User("mary"))
}

object `package` {
  def printTitlePage(course: Course) = "Title page"
}
```

The Scala compiler output is:

```
[error] /var/work/training/experiments/lazyController/src/main/scala/com/micronautics/blah/LazyController.scala:23: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : artifact.type (with underlying type SA)
[error]  required: _$2
[error]         } yield actionInfo.block(artifact)(request)).getOrElse(Html("Not authorized"))
[error]                                  ^
[error] /var/work/training/experiments/lazyController/src/main/scala/com/micronautics/blah/LazyController.scala:24: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : artifact.type (with underlying type SA)
[error]  required: _$2
[error]       } else actionInfo.block(artifact)(request)
[error]                               ^
```

Seems I have not properly specified that a `Course` should be allowable as an instance of an `SA`.

Answer (score 0):

`SecureActionInfo[_]` means the type `_` is unknown (you can write it fully as `SecureActionInfo[X] forSome { type X }`). So there's no way to know whether `SA` is the correct type for it, which is what that compiler error says.

You probably want to make `actionInfo` a `SecureActionInfo[SA]` rather than `SecureActionInfo[_]`. You'll have to either cast it coming out of the `Map` or use a different data structure to preserve the type information.

Comment: I would much prefer a typesafe way to do this (without casting)

Comment: Then you can't use the big `Map` that has all the different `SecureActionInfo[_]`s in and look them up by string. You might be able to do something with a shapeless typed map, but I think a more promising approach is to have a class that contains both the `SecureActionInfo` and the `fetchByArtifact` method.